# iOS - backbarButtonItem: Canceling back?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a backbarButtonItem in ViewController2 and when the screen goes back to its parent viewcontroller, ViewController1, I want to ask the user if he is ready to go back. If he's not ready, I want to give him an option to stay in ViewController. So ask something like - "Are you ready to leave this screen? - YES or NO"

I know that backbarButtonItem cannot call 'action' as defined in Apple doc. Do you have any good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add your own custom leftBarButtonItem to the navigation item, and add whatever action method you want to it. It won't have the same look as the standard back button, but I think that's a good thing -- users expect that the standard button will have a standard behavior. Using a regular rectangular button will alert the users that something different is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Write this in in view didLoad method:

```
    UIImage* myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonImage.png"];
    CGRect backFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30);
    backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:backFrame];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:myimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MyBtnclicked)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
```

and then write ibaction as follows

```
-(IBAction)MyBtnclicked
{
    UIAlertView *av=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Do you really want to Go back" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil]; 
    [av show];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to subclass the `UINavigationController` object and override the `popViewController:animated:` method.  You can then decide, based on the user's response, whether to call super's `popViewController:animated:` or not.